# iOS app rejection because subscriptions do not work on a simulator

Tags: ios, itunes-store

I've got my app rejected because they're testing it in iPad simulator where subscriptions do not work and my app needs to be able to verify subscription before providing an access.

Right now my app is displaying an error "Can't connect to iTunes store, please try again".

What does Apple expect me to do?

Comment: They don't use the simulator to review an app.  Where are you getting that idea?

Comment: I've had this rejection before. If it works on your end, I would just resubmit it again and hope it works for them.